# LaTex underbrace not displaying correctly

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

For some reason, this is what I'm seeing whenever an underbrace is supposed to be displayed on a post on this website:

[image]

It looks like some sort of cropped out icon. It's weird because it doesn't happen on any other device I own.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please include a link to the post where you see this, and say what type of device you see it on.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3599256/714079 this is the post shown in the screenshot. However, it happens on any post where there's an underbrace. The problem appears on a Lenovo IdeaPad laptop, with Ubuntu as my OS and using browser chrome.